# Map an iterator n items at a time

Tags: rust

I am trying to map items of an iterator, N at a time. Something like this:

```
let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
let b = a.iter().map2(|i, j| i + j);
```

`b.collect()` would then yield `b = [3, 7]`

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not as-stated.  You need to break it down into "split vec into iterator of disjoint subsets" and "sum each subset":

```
let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
let b = a.chunks(2).map(|chunk| chunk.iter().sum::<i32>());
println!("b = {:?}", b.collect::<Vec<_>>());
```

Note that this doesn't work when `a` is a general iterator (it relies on it being a slice), though you can get it to work using the [`itertools`](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) crate:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
let a = a.iter().cloned(); // we can't rely on a being a Vec any more.
let b = (&a.chunks(2)).into_iter()
    .map(|chunk| chunk.sum::<i32>())
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
println!("b = {:?}", b);
```

Comment: Any reason not to use `.sum()` on the `Iterator`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Two.  First, it's worse for type inference and you have to explicitly annotate the code.  Second, I predate `Iterator::sum`, so I never remember that it exists when a `fold` will do just fine.

Comment: Fair enough! :D